# Finding an image source on jquery from a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a deleting function. 
I have a php loop where I'm naming the delete image with #PostID at the end. 
I like to get those src name clicking on those buttons with jquery but I can't find it. 
Note that I need to receive the source from the element clicked only.

The php loop looks like this :

```
echo "<td id='erase'><img src='icones/erasing.png#".$id."' height='28'></td>";
```

And the jquery section look like this :

```
$('#table').on('click','#erase img',function(e){
    var idErasing = $(this).prop(src);
    $("#test").text(idErasing);
    // $("#tableau").load('index.php?idErasing='+idErasing+' #tableau');
});
```

Thx for your help

Comment: Chances are you have more than one `td` - if they all have the same `id=` then you're breaking HTML rules where id must be unique, so `$("#id")` will not find what you're expecting.  Change id= to class= and `$(".erase")`

Comment: @Neta did you see my answer? I answered your question before the one you accepted! Please review your choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First it's better to use class in that case and add the id that you need on the image using data attribute:

```
echo "<td class='erase-image'><img data-id='".$id."' src='icones/erasing.png#".$id."' height='28'></td>";
```

From here you can access the id:

```
$('#table').on('click','.erase-image img',function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for